# How to print out values from vector on specific index?

Tags: r

I have a vector with values from 1 to 100 `v1 <- (1:100)`. I would like to get output with values from indexes `44, 50, 51, 52 ... 71`.

I have tried `v1 <- c(seq(44,44), seq(50,71))` but this solution overwrites original vector instead of printing value.

Could you tell me how to get output that I need using only one instruction? Is it possible? I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: are you trying this? `c(44, seq(50,71))`

Comment: Yes, but the output gives just simple numbers. I need to connect this function with vector - because I need values from these indexes (value inside vector may change).

Comment: did you try `v1[c(44, 50:71)]` ?

Comment: @inscaven That should be the correct answer. At least I was about to type it when your comment popped up. I suggest that you post this as an answer since I believe that this will allow to close this question quickly.

Comment: @inscaven No, I didn't. It works, thank you! Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access elements of vector by index using the `[]` operator. So, for your case it would be `v1[c(44, 50:71)]`.

Here we use a vector, containing necessary indexes inside square brackets to define what elements of vector `v1` to choose.

`50:71` is a short form for `seq(50, 71)`

Advice you to get familiar with R manual https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing and in R help by printing `?"["` in cosole.